# Civievent - i cant add any event

Tags: civievent, permissions, acl

I try  to add an event in CiviEvent (with Superadmin role ), but I can not.  After saving the  first form, when Civi tries to go to https://staroflife.pl/civicrm/event/manage/location?action=update&reset=1&id=46 it displays the following error:

```
 $backTrace = 
 #0 /home/sol/domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) 
 #1 /home/sol/domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent.php(128): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Nie masz      uprawnień dostępu do tej strony.")      
 #2 /home/sol/domains/staroflife.pl/     public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent/Location.php(74):      CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent->preProc     ess()      
 #3 /home/sol/domains/staroflife.pl/     public     _html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(543): CRM_Event_Form_Manage     Event_Location->     preProcess()      
 #4 /home/sol/     domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm() 
 #5 /home/sol/     domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203):      CRM_Core_Quic     kForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Location), "display")      
 #6 /home/sol/     domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Pa     ge.php(103): HTML_Q     uickForm_Controller->     handle(Object     (CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Location), "display")      
 #7 /home/sol/     domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/module     s/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display") 
 #8 /home/sol/     domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/module     s/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run() 
 #9 /home/sol/     domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/module     s/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(283): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->     run("CRM_Even     t_Form_ManageEvent_Location", "Lokalizacja wydarze     nia", (Array:0))      
 #10 /home/sol     /domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/modul     es/civicrm/CRM/Co     re/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::ru     nItem((Array:14)) 
 #11 /home/sol     /domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/modul     es/civicrm/CRM/Co     re/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_i     nvoke((Array:4)) 
 #12 /home/sol     /domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/sites/all/modul     es/civicrm/drupal     /civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke:     :invoke((Array:4)) 
 #13 /home/sol     /domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/includes/menu.i     nc(527): civicrm_invoke("event", "manage", "location")      
 #14 /home/sol/domains/staroflife.pl/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() 
 #15 {main}
```

I see the event in the database after this error, but I cannot see it in the dashboard. Before this problem, I add two events without any trouble.

I tried the following: clean Drupal and CiviCRM cache, log in with another login, check ACL in CiviCRM. But it did not work :(

Civicrm version:4.7.19, Drupal: 7.51
"Nie masz      uprawnień dostępu do tej strony." means 
You do not have permission to access this page. :)

**EDIT: The problem occurs when the ID is higher or equal to 30.
I tried: recover old civicrm version (from backup after update) and i have this problem too.**

Comment: Hi @marcin-lewandowski can you complement your question with the CiviCRM version. And I am also curious what the error "Nie masz      uprawnień dostępu do tej strony." means.

Comment: He @Kainuk, thanks for your comment. I use civi with polish language and i forget translate this. :) Sorry

Comment: Google Translate translates this as "You do not have access to this site".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issue and how to fix it. 
I change files in: CRM/event/BAO/event.php

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10325/files